# React Saleor Product Categories

Tags: reactjs, headless, saleor

To whoever has used Saleor with React. There is very little resources for various implementations so I thought I'd ask here.

What is the best way to add colors to products for saleor dashboard? And if possible is there a short example anywhere of how that can be used in storefront react application?
For example I got product with "Size" and "Color" **Variant** Attributes, and "Delivery" and "Returns" **Product** Attributes. Let's say I want to have a product that has 2 sizes and 4 colors. Do I have to create all 8 variants (each color for each size) or is there a better way of doing it?

Because right now what I'm doing is I have 8 variants each size for each color and it's very difficult to manipulate the data that I need in the storefront which is using React.

Essentially what I want to accomplish is have the 2 sizes, and each size has the 4 colors. But the way I'm doing it with variant attributes requires so much data manipulation in the front-end that I'm thinking it's not the right way to do it.

Any suggestions/pointers are appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to add all variants (color × size) since each one of them needs to have a unique identifier SKU which acts as a unique identity of the product (typically a bar code)